# EC.generateKeyPair() missing in Bouncy Castle FIPS library

Tags: java, bouncycastle

[The Bouncy Castle FIPS Java API in 100 Examples](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BCFipsIn100.pdf) suggests multiple times the use of `EC.generateKeyPair()`. Assuming this references `org.bouncycastle.crypto.general.EC` (as this is the only class with name `EC`) I'm not able to find a method `generateKeyPair()`. Where's the error and how to generate an according key pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PDF provided (https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BCFipsIn100.pdf):

> Example 31 – Key Pair Generation
>
> ```
> public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws GeneralSecurityException {
>     KeyPairGenerator keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BCFIPS");
>     keyPair.initialize(384);
>     return keyPair.generateKeyPair();
> }
> ```
>
> The example will result in a key pair on the curve P-384. Other
>   default curves available include P-224, P-256, and P-521.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't looking there, as they refer to `EC.` (as mentioned). Anyway, I guess this helps... I was using a similar approach, but with `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA");`. Do you have any comment on that?

Comment: Take also a look at example 32 if you want to use named curves. 
ECDSA is a DSA style signature based on Elliptic Curves
When you sign using ECDSA, you need EC keys.
But ECDSA would be the signature algorithm, not the key algorithm.